# MTU size for PPPOE with QinQ

Tags: cisco, mtu, qinq, dot1q

i used at as A pppoe server 
i have used QINQ secend tag in rotuer

```
interface TenGigabitEthernet2/0/0.904
 description Cust1-QINQ
 encapsulation dot1Q 904 second-dot1q any
 pppoe enable group PPPOE-SERVER3



interface Virtual-Template2
 **mtu 1492**
 ip unnumbered Loopback0
 ip nat inside
 no logging event link-status
 peer default ip address pool interface localpool2
 keepalive 15
 ppp mtu adaptive
 ppp authentication chap ms-chap ms-chap-v2 eap pap
 ppp ipcp dns 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
 ppp timeout idle 172800 either
end
```

the used is connected but they have some website not open and some application not working too 
i think the issue with MTU because i used double tag (qinq)
so what MTU size must be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the basic way is to use `ping` with the `don't fragment` bit set to ping with various packet size until you find the correct value:

On a Mac OS system use

`ping -D -s <packetsize> <pingable IP accross the tunnel>`

On Windows

`ping -f -l <packetsize> <pingable IP accross the tunnel>`

On linux, the Don't Fragment bit is set by default:

`ping -s <packetsize> <pingable IP accross the tunnel>`

Once you find the maximum value that respond, add 28 for the ICMP (8) and IP (20) headers and you have your MTU.

Comment: hello , 1480 is max size i get ping reachable

Comment: my interface is 1500 , if we add 28 to 1480 is 1508 , so what value i must add